# Creating a Hello World application with Servlet 4.0 (Java EE 8) and HTTP/2

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee

I am trying to understand how Servlets 4 (Java EE 8) help us to gain the benefits of HTTP/2 by writing *Hello World* kind of application. I am aware that Java EE 8 is yet to be released.

- Is there a way I can try these features on beta release of any servlet container like GlashFish?
- Is there a pre release for developers to try out the Java EE 8 API?

Comment: You can try the [GlassFish 5 nightly builds](http://download.oracle.com/glassfish/5.0/nightly/index.html).

Comment: You also can try the [Java Servlet API beta](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api/4.0.0-b01).

Comment: Forget Glassfish (at least until the Oracle really starts to take care about it), but use Payara: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/javaee-guardians/g-DD8EOjst8

Comment: @MiljenMikic Good spot!

Comment: Hi, @Kltis. Did you do a Hello World application in the end? If so I would be interested to know what you did. I am about to embark on the same project. We can share what we have done. Cheers. Alex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Disclaimer:** Once Java EE 8 and the Servlet API 4.0 (which supports HTTP/2) are under development, this answer may not be updated.*

---

### What's currently available (July 6<sup>th</sup> 2016)

At the time of writing, here are a few resources that you may find useful:

- [GlassFish 5 nightly builds](http://download.oracle.com/glassfish/5.0/nightly/index.html) (looks like it's a fork of GlassFish 4.1 and [seems not to incoporate Java EE 8 components](https://java.net/projects/javaee-spec/lists/users/archive/2016-02/message/0)).
- [Java Servlet API 4.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api) JAR (currently released as beta) available on Maven repositories.
- [Apache Tomcat 9](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-90.cgi) (not released as a final version yet), which [supports](https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) the Servlet API 4.0.
- [Payara 5](https://github.com/payara/Payara/tree/Payara-5) (under development), which is a [branch of the Payara project to be used for Java EE 8 features](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/javaee-guardians/g-DD8EOjst8).
- The JSR for the [Java Servlet API 4.0](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=369) (currently available as an early draft).

### More details about Java EE 8

Quoting the [Java EE overview from Oracle website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/overview/index.html):

> As the industry begins the rapid adoption of Java EE 7, work has begun on Java EE 8. With a [survey](https://blogs.oracle.com/ldemichiel/entry/results_from_the_java_ee) that received over 4,500 responses, the community has prioritized the desired features for Java EE 8. In fact, the following JSRs have already been submitted:
>
> - [JSR 366](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=366) - Java EE 8
> - [JSR 367](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=367) - The Java API for JSON Binding
> - [JSR 368](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=368) - Java Message Service 2.1
> - [JSR 369](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=369) - Java Servlet 4.0
> - [JSR 370](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=370) - Java API for RESTful Web Services 2.1
> - [JSR 371](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=371) - Model-View-Controller 1.0
> - [JSR 372](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=372) - Java Server Faces 2.3
> - [JSR 373](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=372) - Java EE Management API 1.0
> - [JSR 374](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=374) - Java API for JSON Processing 1.1
> - [JSR 375](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=375) - Java EE Security API 1.0

The results of the [survey](https://blogs.oracle.com/ldemichiel/entry/results_from_the_java_ee) can be seen in the following chart:

[image: Java EE 8 survey results]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to try out Servlet 4 with server push functionality (the new PushBuilder which allows the server to push data to the client), you need:

- latest glassfish5 nightly build (http://download.oracle.com/glassfish/5.0/nightly/latest-glassfish.zip)
- JDK > 1.8.0_131 + (latest one is _144 at the time of this writing)
- make sure you access the servlet over HTTPS, HTTP/2 doesn't work without SSL apparently.

Check out a complete example here: https://en.kodedu.com/2017/04/first-look-http2-server-push-java-servlet-4-0-specification/

Answer (score 0):

An important requirement when using Servlet 4 and the Server Push feature is that you must secure the connection and an able HTTPS. It is an extra step required when using HTTP/2 on the server and the client is a browser. Here is a blog post about how to set up HTTPS and [Servlet 4.0](https://readlearncode.com/java-ee/configuring-https-servlet-javaee/).

Browsers vendors have implemented HTTP/2 over TLS and even though this is not a specification requirement it is required that you set up a secure connection.

I have a simple example of how to use [Server Push](https://readlearncode.com/java-ee/the-top-5-new-features-in-java-ee-8/) in a servlet that should help get you started.